# Extracting first rows from multiple tables and add one column (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I`m trying to generate a list of the latest currency quotes from Investing.com.

I have the following code:

```
head = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

ISO_Code=[]
Latest=[]
for item in ISO_CURR_ID.ISO_Code[:4]:
    url = 'http://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-'+item+'-historical-data'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=head)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    try:
        CurrHistoricRange = pd.read_html(r.content,attrs = {'id': 'curr_table'}, flavor="bs4")[0]
        Item='USD/'+item
        ISO_Code.append(np.array(Item))
#        Latest.append(np.array(CurrHistoricRange[:1]))
        Latest.append(CurrHistoricRange[:1])
    except:
        pass
```

where ISO_CURR_ID.ISO_Code is:

```
In [69]:ISO_CURR_ID.ISO_Code[:4]
Out[69]: 
0    EUR
1    GBP
2    JPY
3    CHF
```

I need the final format to be a table Like this

```
  ISO_Code    Date        Price    Open    High   Low Change %
0   EUR    Jun 21, 2016, 0.8877, 0.8833, 0.8893, 0.881, -0.14%
```

But I`m having problems to undestand how to merge those first rows without repeating column names. So I`m getting a result like this if I use

```
Final=pd.DataFrame(dict(ISO_Code = ISO_Code, Latest_Quotes = Latest))


Final
Out[71]: 
  ISO_Code                                      Latest_Quotes
0  USD/EUR             Date   Price    Open    High    Low...
1  USD/GBP             Date   Price    Open    High     Lo...
2  USD/JPY             Date   Price    Open    High    Low...
3  USD/CHF             Date   Price   Open    High     Low...
```

Comment: Can you post a desired output (5-7 rows should be enough)?

Comment: Desired outup is in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a cleaner way to accomplish what you are trying to do

```
head = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

latest_data=[]

for item in ISO_CURR_ID.ISO_Code:
    url = 'http://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-'+item+'-historical-data'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=head)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    try:
        CurrHistoricRange = pd.read_html(r.content,attrs = {'id': 'curr_table'}, flavor="bs4")[0]
        Item='USD/'+item
        data = CurrHistoricRange.iloc[0].to_dict()
        data["ISO_Code"] = Item
        latest_data.append(data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def getDf(latest_list, order = ["ISO_Code", "Date", "Price", "Open", "High", "Low", "Change %"]):
    return pd.DataFrame(latest_list, columns=order)

getDf(latest_data)
```

Outputs:

```
    ISO_Code    Date     Price  Open    High    Low     Change %
0   USD/EUR     Jun 21, 2016    0.8882  0.8833  0.8893  0.8810  0.55%
1   USD/GBP     Jun 21, 2016    0.6822  0.6815  0.6829  0.6766  0.10%
2   USD/JPY     Jun 21, 2016    104.75  103.82  104.82  103.60  0.88%
3   USD/CHF     Jun 21, 2016    0.9613  0.9620  0.9623  0.9572  -0.07%
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [pandas.Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#panels) for that, similar to pandas_datareader:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

head = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

ISO_Code=[]
Latest=[]
URL = 'http://www.investing.com/currencies/usd-{}-historical-data'
dfs = {}

curr_ser = pd.Series(['EUR','GBP','JPY','CHF'])


#for item in ISO_CURR_ID.ISO_Code[:4]:
for item in curr_ser:
    url = URL.format(item)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=head)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    try:
        Item='USD/'+item
        dfs[Item] = pd.read_html(r.content,attrs = {'id': 'curr_table'}, flavor="bs4")[0]
        #CurrHistoricRange = pd.read_html(r.content,attrs = {'id': 'curr_table'}, flavor="bs4")[0]
        #ISO_Code.append(np.array(Item))
        #Latest.append(np.array(CurrHistoricRange[:1]))
        #Latest.append(CurrHistoricRange[:1])
    except:
        pass

# create Panel out of dictionary of DataFrames
p = pd.Panel(dfs)

# slice first row from all DFs
t = p[:,0,:]

print(t)
print(t.T)
```

Output:

```
               USD/CHF       USD/EUR       USD/GBP       USD/JPY
Date      Jun 21, 2016  Jun 21, 2016  Jun 21, 2016  Jun 21, 2016
Price           0.9618        0.8887        0.6828        104.97
Open             0.962        0.8833        0.6815        103.82
High            0.9623        0.8893        0.6829        104.97
Low             0.9572         0.881        0.6766         103.6
Change %        -0.02%         0.61%         0.19%         1.09%

                 Date   Price    Open    High     Low Change %
USD/CHF  Jun 21, 2016  0.9618   0.962  0.9623  0.9572   -0.02%
USD/EUR  Jun 21, 2016  0.8887  0.8833  0.8893   0.881    0.61%
USD/GBP  Jun 21, 2016  0.6828  0.6815  0.6829  0.6766    0.19%
USD/JPY  Jun 21, 2016  104.97  103.82  104.97   103.6    1.09%
```

**and if we sort DF's indices (by dates) like this:**

```
    dfs[Item] = pd.read_html(r.content,
                             attrs = {'id': 'curr_table'},
                             flavor="bs4",
                             parse_dates=['Date'],
                             index_col=[0]
                )[0].sort_index()

# create Panel out of dictionary of DataFrames
p = pd.Panel(dfs)
```

now we can do a lot of funny things:

```
In [18]: p.axes
Out[18]:
[Index(['USD/CHF', 'USD/EUR', 'USD/GBP', 'USD/JPY'], dtype='object'),
 DatetimeIndex(['2016-05-23', '2016-05-24', '2016-05-25', '2016-05-26', '2016-05-27', '2016-05-30', '2016-05-31', '2016-06-01', '2016-06-02', '20
16-06-03', '2016-06-06', '2016-06-07', '2016-06-08',
                '2016-06-09', '2016-06-10', '2016-06-13', '2016-06-14', '2016-06-15', '2016-06-16', '2016-06-17', '2016-06-19', '2016-06-20', '20
16-06-21'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None),
 Index(['Price', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Change %'], dtype='object')]

In [19]: p.keys()
Out[19]: Index(['USD/CHF', 'USD/EUR', 'USD/GBP', 'USD/JPY'], dtype='object')

In [22]: p.to_frame().head(10)
Out[22]:
                    USD/CHF USD/EUR USD/GBP USD/JPY
Date       minor
2016-05-23 Price     0.9896  0.8913  0.6904  109.23
           Open      0.9905  0.8913  0.6893  110.08
           High      0.9924  0.8942  0.6925  110.25
           Low       0.9879  0.8893  0.6872  109.08
           Change %  -0.06%   0.03%   0.12%  -0.84%
2016-05-24 Price     0.9933  0.8976  0.6833  109.99
           Open      0.9892   0.891  0.6903  109.22
           High      0.9946  0.8983  0.6911  110.12
           Low       0.9882  0.8906  0.6827  109.14
           Change %   0.37%   0.71%  -1.03%   0.70%
```

indexing by currency pair and by dates

```
In [25]: p['USD/EUR', '2016-06-10':'2016-06-15', :]
Out[25]:
             Price    Open    High     Low Change %
Date
2016-06-10  0.8889  0.8835  0.8893  0.8825    0.59%
2016-06-13  0.8855  0.8885  0.8903  0.8846   -0.38%
2016-06-14  0.8922  0.8856  0.8939  0.8846    0.76%
2016-06-15  0.8881   0.892  0.8939  0.8848   -0.46%
```

index by currency pair

```
In [26]: p['USD/EUR', :, :]
Out[26]:
             Price    Open    High     Low Change %
Date
2016-05-23  0.8913  0.8913  0.8942  0.8893    0.03%
2016-05-24  0.8976   0.891  0.8983  0.8906    0.71%
2016-05-25  0.8964  0.8974  0.8986  0.8953   -0.13%
2016-05-26  0.8933  0.8963  0.8975  0.8913   -0.35%
2016-05-27  0.8997  0.8931  0.9003  0.8926    0.72%
2016-05-30  0.8971  0.8995  0.9012  0.8969   -0.29%
2016-05-31  0.8983  0.8975  0.8993  0.8949    0.13%
2016-06-01  0.8938  0.8981     0.9  0.8929   -0.50%
2016-06-02  0.8968  0.8937  0.8974  0.8911    0.34%
2016-06-03  0.8798  0.8968  0.8981  0.8787   -1.90%
2016-06-06  0.8807  0.8807  0.8831  0.8777    0.10%
2016-06-07  0.8804  0.8805  0.8821  0.8785   -0.03%
2016-06-08  0.8777  0.8803  0.8812  0.8762   -0.31%
2016-06-09  0.8837   0.877  0.8847  0.8758    0.68%
2016-06-10  0.8889  0.8835  0.8893  0.8825    0.59%
2016-06-13  0.8855  0.8885  0.8903  0.8846   -0.38%
2016-06-14  0.8922  0.8856  0.8939  0.8846    0.76%
2016-06-15  0.8881   0.892  0.8939  0.8848   -0.46%
2016-06-16  0.8908  0.8879  0.8986  0.8851    0.30%
2016-06-17  0.8868  0.8907  0.8914   0.885   -0.45%
2016-06-19  0.8813  0.8822  0.8841  0.8811   -0.63%
2016-06-20  0.8833  0.8861  0.8864  0.8783    0.23%
2016-06-21  0.8891  0.8833  0.8893   0.881    0.66%
```

index by date

```
In [28]: p[:, '2016-06-20', :]
Out[28]:
         USD/CHF USD/EUR USD/GBP USD/JPY
Price      0.962  0.8833  0.6815  103.84
Open      0.9599  0.8861  0.6857  104.63
High      0.9633  0.8864  0.6881  104.84
Low       0.9576  0.8783  0.6794  103.78
Change %   0.22%   0.23%  -0.61%  -0.75%

In [29]: p[:, :, 'Change %']
Out[29]:
           USD/CHF USD/EUR USD/GBP USD/JPY
Date
2016-05-23  -0.06%   0.03%   0.12%  -0.84%
2016-05-24   0.37%   0.71%  -1.03%   0.70%
2016-05-25  -0.20%  -0.13%  -0.42%   0.18%
2016-05-26  -0.20%  -0.35%   0.18%  -0.38%
2016-05-27   0.55%   0.72%   0.31%   0.42%
2016-05-30  -0.25%  -0.29%  -0.07%   0.82%
2016-05-31   0.14%   0.13%   1.10%  -0.38%
2016-06-01  -0.55%  -0.50%   0.42%  -1.07%
2016-06-02   0.23%   0.34%  -0.04%  -0.61%
2016-06-03  -1.45%  -1.90%  -0.66%  -2.14%
2016-06-06  -0.56%   0.10%   0.55%   0.97%
2016-06-07  -0.55%  -0.03%  -0.71%  -0.19%
2016-06-08  -0.62%  -0.31%   0.28%  -0.35%
2016-06-09   0.55%   0.68%   0.30%   0.10%
2016-06-10   0.02%   0.59%   1.42%  -0.10%
2016-06-13  -0.03%  -0.38%  -0.11%  -0.68%
2016-06-14  -0.11%   0.76%   1.11%  -0.13%
2016-06-15  -0.21%  -0.46%  -0.64%  -0.08%
2016-06-16   0.40%   0.30%   0.03%  -1.67%
2016-06-17  -0.54%  -0.45%  -1.08%  -0.12%
2016-06-19   0.00%  -0.63%  -1.55%   0.48%
2016-06-20   0.22%   0.23%  -0.61%  -0.75%
2016-06-21   0.02%   0.66%   0.35%   0.98%
```

index by two axes

```
In [30]: p[:, '2016-06-10':'2016-06-15', 'Change %']
Out[30]:
           USD/CHF USD/EUR USD/GBP USD/JPY
Date
2016-06-10   0.02%   0.59%   1.42%  -0.10%
2016-06-13  -0.03%  -0.38%  -0.11%  -0.68%
2016-06-14  -0.11%   0.76%   1.11%  -0.13%
2016-06-15  -0.21%  -0.46%  -0.64%  -0.08%
```